# Why it does not navigate to the right URL?

Tags: javascript, web, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I am trying to setup my first E2E test with [Nightwatch](https://nightwatchjs.org/) on the chromium browser.

*nightwatch.json* is configured as the following:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],

  "webdriver" : {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "node_modules/.bin/chromedriver",
    "port": 9515
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the test:

```
module.exports = {
    'Demo test ecosia.org': function (browser) {
        browser
            .url('https://www.ecosia.org/')
            .waitForElementVisible('body')
            .assert.titleContains('Ecosia')
            .assert.visible('input[type=search]')
            .setValue('input[type=search]', 'nightwatch')
            .assert.visible('button[type=submit]')
            .click('button[type=submit]')
            .assert.containsText('.mainline-results', 'Nightwatch.js')
            .end();
    }
};
```

When I start test, it shows in the chromium browser:
[image]

The output:

```
[First Spec] Test Suite
=======================
⚠ Error connecting to localhost on port 9515.
_________________________________________________

TEST FAILURE: 1 error during execution; 0 tests failed, 0 passed (10.238s)

 ✖ first_spec
   An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally."
Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally."
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

  Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally."
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: copied your code and it works just fine :/

Comment: Really, it is something wrong with my chromium browser? @davbuc Did you try it with the chromium browser?

Comment: Yes i copied both files you have in your question, so it is with chromium. (btw never used nightwatch before). What is the output in the console (terminal and chromium)?

Comment: @davbuc I have updated my post.

Comment: Thanks, but not really what I hoped for. Which node version are you on? And which chromium version has been installed in your node_modules?

Comment: Node 12.18.4, Chromium 85.0.4183.121 and "chromedriver": "^85.0.1",

Comment: well we have the exact same setup.. how do you start nightwatch?

Comment: With the statement `nightwatch`

Answer (score 0):

Check your Chrome version and its chrome driver compatibility.
This seems to be a driver compatibility issue.
Also, do check this page for more information
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
Thanks!